# how to restore reducer state value to the initialState default value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to filter items by their category using useReducer

*context.jsx*

```
const initialState = {
    categoryName: "all item",
  };

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

const fetchUrl = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    const respData = await resp.json();
    const item = respData.item;
    const category = respData.category;
    const promo = respData.promo;
    dispatch({ type: "CATEGORY_ITEM", payload: category });
  };
```

I want to display the category name that matched the data.

*reducer.jsx*

```
if (action.type === "FILTER_NAME") {
    if (action.payload === "all menu") {
      return { ...state, categoryName: "all menu" };
    //return { ...state, categoryName: state.categoryName};
    } else {
      return { ...state, categoryName: action.payload };
    }
  }
```

I cant set the `categoryName` back to the state value because it's been changed when I do `else`.

Is there a way for me to set a default value in reducer? Because if I use `useState` the `setState` won't overwrite the `state` default value.
Thanks before

Comment: Hard to follow what you're asking for, to be frank with you.

Comment: so basically I will display an item that matched the clicked button name. And I want to display the category name that matched the data with the default one is ```all menu```. So for example when I click ```banana``` menu it will display banana and update the ```categoryName``` with banana. So I want to display the default value which is ```all menu``` when user click it, but since it got overwrite by the new value it won't do it.

Comment: You need to dispatch some sort of "RESET_STATE" action.  In the reducer, `return {...state, categoryName: initialState.categoryName}`

Comment: The `if/else` in your reducer is pointless because `"all menu"` and `action.payload` are the same in the `if` branch.  In this current setup your reducer is expecting you to reset the category name state by calling `dispatch({type: "FILTER_NAME", payload: "all menu"})`.